# Events Not Showing Up in Properties Tab - VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I face a very different problem that I really don't get a clue on what to do. The events option(lightning option present in the properties tab) is not Showing Up in Properties Tab. Could anyone show me path in resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/1369803/2858924.aspx) has some discussion if you're developing an ASP .NET application and can't see the events.

Answer (score 0):

The problem still exists in VS2017.  I have a two step process that works for me.  Fist click on the option split at the bottom, and then touch the item in the code. as in what is to the right of the asp:.  So with asp:GridView, click on Gridview, not any of the parameters following.